# Minimum number of steps required to cut this bar

Tags: geometry, strategy, visual

What is the minimum number of steps required to cut this chocolate bar which is a single piece into at least 30 single pieces?

> 1)Image for chocolate bar
>
> [image: Chocolate bar]
>
> 2)Image for single piece
>
> [image]

**Edit:**
Your knife is only as long as the width of a single piece and stacking (laying rows or columns on top of each other when you've cut those lose) is not allowed.

Comment: I have edited it i am looking for at least 30 single pieces

Comment: if we cut all the columns so you have 5 separate columns of 8, can we lay them next to each other to cut the rows, so cutting a row takes 1 cut instead of 5 seperate ones.

Comment: nope that's not allowed i would edit my question for this...

Comment: your edit is unclear. Do you mean you cannot lay cut pieces one on TOP of another to have cuts affect multiple areas, or do you mean you cannot cut more than the 'length' of the piece at a time.

Comment: Your edit makes cutting vertically take 8 cuts since you can not make a cut that is the length of the whole bar.

Comment: @IanMacDonald and side ways would take 4. At least that's how I interpeted it, and with that i don't think stacking them is allowed either.

Comment: Which means this puzzle is just about counting.  Not much of a puzzle.

Comment: @Spacemonkey nope there are different ways to count, you can have 60, 57 and 50 for as far as i know, so it is asking for the best way, and since there are multiple ways it still is a puzzle

Comment: OOooooooh I get it , lol I just noticed theres 40 pieces, and the question is how many cuts for 30. I just assumed right off the start there was 30 and never checked. lol. The world makes sense again, all is good

Comment: How hard is it to break a chocolate bar with your hands?

Comment: @mdc32 it can be extremely difficult for some bars, they never break up in nice evenly pieces.

Comment: Can't seem to find a way to get less than 54 so I deleted my answer, 3 others already gave it :P

Comment: @Spacemonkey ye everyone is copying me :P though kaine's answer has a formula and a picture in it.

Comment: Ah ha! I found a way!! xD   My new total is 40

Comment: You should change the wording to not redefine "single piece".  The sentence "cut this chocolate bar which is a *single piece* into at least 30 *single pieces*" is confusing.

Comment: Wait... are we supposed to ignore the fact that the width is longer than the height?

Comment: @kaine: yeah; cutting out a column should only take 7 cuts, not 8. I got 51 cuts that way. (Leave the top 5 pieces in the rightmost 2 columns)

Comment: Being tricky: cut a few rows loose, then lay them on a cut edge to cut more than one at a time. While stacking isn't allowed, laying them on edge is not specifically disallowed. (Yet.)

Comment: Do the single pieces need to be cut along the lines, or can they be any piece of that size and shape? Can you move parts without stacking once you've cut them?

Comment: why so many downvotes

Comment: Guys seriously, stop the literal thinking, don't be so annoying, you know how the question is intended to be. Don't know @user2408578, but don't forget to select an answer when the right one shows up ;)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

> 54. my previous answer still hold but you have to make 5 cuts instead of 1 when trying to seperate a row. so 6 * 5 + 4 * 6 = 54.

I would say (after edit of the question this answer is no longer viable):

> 24 cuts first 6 cuts to get 6 seperate rows (you will keep 1 piece with 2 rows attached) then you have to cut each column which requires 4 cuts, so 4 * 6 = 24.

edited calculation error.

Comment: i have edited it....but you answered it so fast...give it another try

Comment: @user2408578 I've edited it, is this correct?

Comment: If anything, wouldn't it be 54? And also, how is this better than the most basic way of cutting from the top?

Comment: @mdc32 6 * 5 = 30 and 4 * 5 = 20, how's 30 + 20 = 54? Also you could do it cutting from the left top to the bottom (giving you 8 pieces after 15 cuts) this would be 57 cuts for 30 pieces)

Comment: @mdc32 you were right, i've fixed my mistake, well spotted

Answer (score 3):

My answer is

> 54, because almost every piece needs to be cut at least 2 times starting from second top piece and go around bar, 3 corner pieces will be ignored as they will be cut because of other pieces.

Answer (score 2):

All this thinking made me hungry so I figured I'd eat the chocolate pieces we didn't need. (sorry)

I ended up with

> **40**
>
> [image]

*Disclaimer: This is not meant as a serious answer, it's meant to make you smile.*

Comment: It made me smile so +1, to be fair it did not say you could or could not eat some of the pieces ;)

Answer (score 2):

"What is the minimum number of steps required to cut this chocolate bar which is a single piece into at least 30 single pieces?"

I hope this question isn't about word play, but until it's stated I'll keep this as an option.

My answer is:

> 3. There are only three steps required. 1. Cut a chocolate bar edge. 2. Check/Stop if we have 30 pieces. 3. Repeat previous steps.
>  
>  Alternatively if you are some sort of savage, you can use just 1 step: Cut all the chocolate bar edges.

Comment: This is the most interesting answer, I think.

Comment: Why not just: 1) Cut all chocolate bar edges.

Comment: @mbeckish, That's just being a savage!

Answer (score 1):

The simplist solution is 54:

> [image]

Note that there are 6 rows of 5 horizontal cuts and 4 rows of 6 vertical cuts.

We want to maximize the remaining number of uncut lengths.  For an $X*Y$ rectangle, the number of uncut lengths is equal to $(4*X*Y-2*(Y+X))/2$.  For $X*Y=10$ this becomes $20-10/X-X$.  The maximum integer value for this is $X=3$ but Y must be an integer so this doesn't work.  This best solution, therefore, is for $X=2$ and $Y=5$.

If we assume that the vertical cuts are $5/6$ the length of horizontal cuts, we can improve this even further.  The image above would only use 50 cuts as the long vertical lengths need one less cut to complete them.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as everyone else:

> 54

You can come to this conclusion without trying all of the different cutting patterns.

The total number of edges that connect one piece to another is 67.  Minimizing the number of cuts is equivalent to maximizing the number of edges that remain uncut.

So the problem reduces to choosing 10 or less pieces that are part of your "remainder" such that their total number of uncut edges is maximized.

The most uncut edges I have been able to find amongst 10 or less pieces is:

> 13

which gives me the same result as everyone else.